# In Ruby on Rails, to extend the String class, where should the code be put in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If on Ruby on Rails, I need to add a method called

```
class String
  def capitalize_first
    # ...
  end
end
```

and wonder where should the file go to?  (which directory and filename, and is any initialize code needed?)  This is for a Rails 3.0.6 project.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I always add a `core_ext` directory in my `lib` dir.

Create an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files) for loading the custom extensions (for example: `config/initializers/core_exts.rb`). And add the following line in it:

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "core_ext", "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }
```

and have your extension like:

`lib/core_ext/string.rb`

```
class String
  def capitalize_first
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I wonder... should we extend the `String` class or just use a helper method in view?  But then, if it is a helper, then it is also troublesome to make it work in controller (or model), and it cannot be chained like `s.capitalize_first.truncate(30)`

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but could you give an example of an "initializer config" thanks

Comment: I placed it in config/application.rb:

`class Application < Rails::Application
...
config.autoload_paths += Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "core_ext", "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }
...`

Comment: Definitely the way to go if you want a scalable solution

Comment: If you put the extension within `lib/core_ext/string.rb`, don't forget to include `require 'core_ext/string'` at the top of the file where you use it.

Comment: I needed to add `app` to the file path: `Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "app", "lib", "core_ext", "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }`

Comment: @moondaisy you are wrong. `lib` directory should not be inside the `app` directory.

Comment: Rails 5 seems to have changed how it loads class files (e.g. `config.autoload_paths`), which could cause some issues.

Comment: How do you do it in Rails 6?

Comment: @Taschetto Add the line `Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(Rails.root.join('lib/core_ext'))` at the start of the initializer to prevent conflicts with the "new" Zeitwork autoloader. Since you manually load the files in the initializer anyway, they can be excluded from being autoloaded by Zeitwork. For more info, see: https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#ignoring-parts-of-the-project

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284058/why-use-app-lib-instead-of-lib-in-rails.

Answer (score 66):

You could do it in config/initializers/string.rb

```
class String
  def capitalize_first
    # ...
  end
end
```

should be all you need (besides an app restart).

Comment: I'm curious to where would you add a test file for this extension?

Comment: Easiest method, yes. But you loose support for reloading this class when you make changes in development.

Answer (score 7):

The guidelines in Rails 3.1 is the way to go:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#extending-core-classes

If you follow the default convention you won't need to mess with an initializer config.

Comment: This method does not eager load the extension. It loads it after you call the module/class name (from this rails guide, it's Yaffle). This means you won't be able to call the extension method until the module name (Yaffle) is called first and you cannot define this module name in initializers. I've tested it in the console and it's how autoload_paths works. Requiring the extension file in config/initializers/ or in config/application.rb are the best options.

Comment: @konyak - thanks for the explanation - what is the point of the ruby-on-rails docs then, are they outdated?

Comment: I still upvoted because it's a very interesting article.