# Top-level method can be accessed from another class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How is it possible that if I define a method in the Object class (which is defined as private), I am able to call it from inside another class? I mean, when I call say_hello from inside the class Dog, how is it resolved if say_hello is a top-level defined method and therefore is private to the Object class? I know the Object class is in the method lookup of all the classes, but if the method is private it should not be accessible right?

```
def say_hello
  p "Hello"
end
class Dog
  def test_hello
    say_hello
  end
end

prova = Dog.new
prova.test_hello
```

I guess an easier explanation of my doubt would be: Why can I call a private method of a parent from a child?

```
class Animal
  private
  def prova
    p "hello"
  end
end
class Dog < Animal
  def test_hello
    prova
  end
end

prova = Dog.new
prova.test_hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember `Dog` inherits from `Object`, giving it access to `Object`s methods.  You can extend the Object class all you want.

See answer to: [How to extend class Object in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847220/how-to-extend-class-object-in-rails)

Comment: I didn't know that in Ruby, extended classes have access to private methods of its parents...

Answer (score 0):

> but if the method is private it should not be accessible right?

What makes you think that?

Private methods can only be called with an implicit receiver. You *are* calling it with an implicit receiver. Ergo, it should work … and it does.