# Add translation to I18N dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

I have added humanized-money-accessors as described here: [Decimals and commas when entering a number into a Ruby on Rails form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541209/decimals-and-commas-when-entering-a-number-into-a-ruby-on-rails-form)

Now I have two attributes in my model for the same type of data: the original version and the human-readable version. The problem: Since I am using activerecord-translation-yml-files, I have to put in the same translation for original attribute and the humanized_attribute, because my forms show the name of thie humanized_attribute, but on validation errors, the name of the original attribute is shown.

Is it possible to add translations dynamically? This way I could add the translation for the humanized-version of the field when the humanized_accessor-class-method is called, getting the original translation string from the yml file, instead of writing both of them (with the same value) into the yml-file, just to have more DRY.

Answer (score 4):

This is dependent on the `I18n` gem's internal API not changing but it is possible using [`I18n.backend.store_translations`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb#L33).

This contrived example demonstrates:

```
I18n.with_locale(:fake_locale) { I18n.t('some_word') }
  => "translation missing: fake_locale.some_word"

I18n.backend.store_translations(:fake_locale, some_word: 'fake translation')

I18n.with_locale(:fake_locale) { I18n.t('some_word') }
  => "fake translation"
```

**Important:** This is only done in memory. Some persistence or re-generation mechanism is necessary to prevent these from disappearing when you redeploy/restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out globalize3 gem. You have railscast tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3?view=asciicast.