# Add translation into i18n locales of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I want to create a simple form that adds translations dynamically into `config/locales/en.rb`. There's a way to do this? I'll need something like a parser to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

With using Globalize3 gem given here on stack-overflow answer [Add translation to I18N dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072424/add-translation-to-i18n-dynamically?rq=1)

Rails cast link:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3?view=asciicast