# How to strip commas from float input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a field -

```
:Revenue
```

and it should accept values like `10,000.00`, but if I input such value it stores `10` into database instead of `10000.00`

What should I do to strip of commas before I save?

I've tried to find a few solutions online but wasn't able to implement them as I found them incomplete. If someone could help me I would really appreciate it.

**The problem now I am facing is that as soon as I enter the value rails converts string in to float value before it can run the gsub function, like if I enter 50,000.00 its converting into float 50.0 before calling the gsub, is there any way to over the to_f method which rails is calling on the string.

Comment: What were those `incomplete` solutions?

Comment: See if this helps. I think it is exactly what you're trying to do and is more complete than the answer I had given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541209/decimals-and-commas-when-entering-a-number-into-a-ruby-on-rails-form  Go to the answer that has **5** points.

Answer (score 13):

Removing commas is pretty simple:

```
value.gsub(/,/, '').to_f
```

Keep in mind that European formatting often uses comma as the decimal value separator so your results would be off by a factor of 100 if processing those sorts of numbers.

Comment: Unless you can guarantee that there will be at least one comma, you will not want to use the bang method, otherwise your value will go from 10,000.00 to 0.

Comment: "NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `gsub' for 50.0:Float" if i enter something like 50,000.00

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar If you are trying this on a float, you've already done the conversion and it's too late. Maybe you need to process the `params` before you link them up with the model?

Comment: do u know how can i process the params before i link it up with the database?

Comment: In your controller if you have one. You haven't provided any code so I can only guess.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a [`String#delete`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-delete).

```
"10,000,000.00".delete(',').to_f 
# => 10000000.0
```

Comment: This has the same problem as gsub! if you can't guarantee there will be a comma, you will get 0 rather than 10 million.

Comment: the problem is as soon as enter 10,000.0 and click on submit it converts it into a float so it becomes 10, i want to use gsub or delete in this case before that happens

Comment: @vgoff changed the post.. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after looking at few places and combining few solutions, since I had to use gsub before the linking to model has to be done. so I created the method in my controller and called it before create and update action. and wrote the following code in the method

```
params[:record][:Revenue] = params[:record][:Revenue].gsub(/,/,"")
```