# Ancestry gem: return only last child in threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem has a lot of methods to navigate the tree structure. You can do Model.roots to show all root elements etc. How do opposite? - return newest child for each tree structure.

I thought about adding an extra column to my model (latest/boolean) and then do some logic with after save filters etc. However this feels a bit clumsy. :/

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can hack something together with the `Class#inherited` hook, like updating an attribute of the parent model on creation of the new subclass:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Class.html#M000177

Answer (score 0):

Old question, still relevant. 
Found myself a solution (bit clumsy as well) but I think it works fairly well.

Extend the Array class with a method like this:

```
class Array

  def ancestry_last_child
    last_child = self.map { |a| [a[:id], a[:ancestry], a[:updated_at]] }.sort_by { |id, anc, dat| [anc.split('/').length, dat] }.last
    self.find { |a| a[:id] == last_child[0] }
  end

end
```

After that just use it (with preceding validation) like this:

```
account = Account.find([id])

if account.has_children?
  last_child = account.descendants.ancestry_last_child
end
```

if you have doubts about extending ruby/rails core classes [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654517/in-ruby-on-rails-to-extend-the-string-class-where-should-the-code-be-put-in) will help

::EDIT::
previous solution didn't work in full. This solution requires an `updated_at` and `id` column