# In Rails, how to add a new method to String class?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, monkeypatching

I want to build an index for different objects in my Rails project and would like to add a 'count_occurences' method that I can call on String objects.

I saw I could do something like

```
class String
  def self.count_occurences
    do_something_here
  end
end
```

What's the exact way to define this method, and where to put the code in my Rails project?

Thanks

Comment: This is ugly. What if an other library also adds a `count_occurences` method that doesn't do exactly the same thing ?

Comment: presumably something else doesn't have that method or he would have been using it already

Comment: If you're new to monkeypatching, you may want to browse other Stack Overflow questions tagged ruby and monkeypatching.

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/a/5654574/3159183, you can actually just place your code into `config/initializers/string.rb` and be done (after  restarting your server)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can define a new class in your application at `lib/ext/string.rb` and put this content in it:

```
class String
  def to_magic
    "magic"
  end
end
```

To load this class, you will need to require it in your `config/application.rb` file or in an initializer. If you had many of these extensions, an initializer is better! The way to load it is simple:

```
require 'ext/string'
```

The `to_magic` method will then be available on *instances* of the `String` class inside your application / console, i.e.:

```
>> "not magic".to_magic
=> "magic"
```

No plugins necessary.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! Just one question: why isn't the file loaded with "config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)"?

Comment: @alex: It would be, but you would need to restart your server or console, depending on what you're using to access it. The `autoload_paths` option configures directories containing files which will be automatically loaded, and so if it's *not* being loaded I suspect you've not done of those two things I just said.

Comment: ok. all i needed to know! thank you so much. and oh, by the way, I just received Rails 3 in Action yesterday... looking forward to reading it!

Comment: @RyanBigg: not sure why your instruction didn't work for me. Might be some set up issue. I am using Rails 3.0.7. here is what I did to make it work:  1. add config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/ext"]   to config/application.rb   2.  add require 'ext/string.rb'  to  the actual rails file in need of such custom String method.   But thanks for your helpful posts. I got it to work!

Comment: @RyanBigg thanks for the hint with the initializers. I put it into `config/initializers/load_class_extensions.rb` and require it from there now.

Comment: doesn't work for me, it's something different in rails 5?

Comment: @Daniel If you place the above code in `config/initializers/string.rb`, you don't even need to `require` it explicitly. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5654574/3159183

Answer (score 14):

I know this is an old thread, but it doesn't seem as if the accepted solution works in Rails 4+ (at least not for me). Putting the extension rb file in to config/initializers worked.

Alternatively, you can add /lib to the Rails autoloader (in config/application.rb, in the Application class:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

require 'ext/string'
```

See this:
http://brettu.com/rails-ruby-tips-203-load-lib-files-in-rails-4/

Answer (score 6):

When you want to extend some core class then you usually want to create a plugin (it is handy when need this code in another application). Here you can find a guide how to create a plugin http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html and point #3 show you how to extend String class: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#extending-core-classes

Comment: Is there a way I could accomplish the same thing without having to create a full plugin (which seems a lot of work for what I want to accomplish...)?

Comment: I know the other solution that Ryan post and it is also correct. No doubt about it. But I recommended you plugin because this is what we do in our company. When you create a plugin you can put it on github and everyone can install it to his/her application. I know that this is more work but it is usually worth it. And I really don't feel that I deserved deducted point in here...