# Where should Ruby monkey patches be placed within a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am planning to use a Ruby module to add a function to the String class. http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/584-generating-word-n-grams-with-ruby

However, I don't know where to put Ruby modules so that every string object can use this function.

Where do I put modules in Rails?

Comment: Another possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/7490680/1290374

Answer (score 3):

Methods like this often go in the `config/initializers` directory, ruby files contained in that directory are automatically required when Rails boots up.

Another option is within `lib`, but then they'll have to be explicitly required somewhere.

See the Rails guide on [Configuring Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files) for more information.

Comment: Putting the guts in `lib` and then a one-liner `require 'thing-in-lib'` in `config/initializers` seems to be a pretty common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in `app/helpers` with some name like `common_methods.rb` and then add it into your controller using `require 'common_methods'`. So that you can use the same function in all controllers.