# How do I extend the Time class in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Basically I'd like to extend the Time class to add this method:

```
def round_to_fifteen()
    return Time.at((self.to_i / 900).round * 900)
end
```

How do I achieve this and where should I put the file that extends the Class?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7491707/877472) seems to have the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conventionally, this kind of thing goes in `lib/`. I'd just have something like `lib/time_extensions.rb` which is required from an initializer.

You would simply re-open the Time class and add the method desired, like so:

```
class Time
  def round_to_fifteen()
    return Time.at((self.to_i / 900).round * 900)
  end
end
```

Then, any Time object will have the `#round_to_fifteen` method available. You can see this in the console:

```
2.0.0p247 :004 > class Time
2.0.0p247 :005?>   def round_to_fifteen()
2.0.0p247 :006?>       return Time.at((self.to_i / 900).round * 900)
2.0.0p247 :007?>     end
2.0.0p247 :008?> end
 => nil
2.0.0p247 :009 > Time.now.round_to_fifteen
 => 2013-12-28 13:15:00 -0700
```

Comment: I'm sorry to be a complete 'Noob' but how do I require it from an initializer?

Comment: Rails has the config/initializers directory. You can create a file in there (I like mine called something like `01_includes.rb` or whatnot), then `require File.join(Rails.root, 'lib/time_extensions')` in there. That'll require your extensions file when Rails boots up, re-open the Time class, and add your method.

Answer (score 1):

You could literally put this anywhere you want to use it, you could write

```
    class Time

      def round_to_fifteen
        return Time.at((self.to_i / 900).round * 900)
      end
    end
```

To use this, you would just write

```
timestamp_object.round_to_fifteen
```

Comment: I'm not a Python guy, but I did answer the question, no?

Comment: This isn't going to work - you have to reopen the Time class if you want to extend it. This code defines a new `UsersHeper::Time` class, which is not the same as the `::Time` class.

Comment: Ha! you were right, that was very foolish of me. I've edited my answer to improve accuracy