# What is the correct way to extend the core in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I always find it useful to extend ruby's core, such as `Object` or `String` classes.

What is the correct and most organized way to extend the core? should i make files for each class i extend in the `initializers` or `libs` directory?

Comment: Have a look at this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654517/in-ruby-on-rails-to-extend-the-string-class-where-should-the-code-be-put-in
I'd say this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing, I would treat the code for the extensions like a local gem that is located in your lib/ directory, but required from an initializer called something like "core_extensions.rb".