# Rails extending Date class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a file `lib/ext/date.rb` which extends the `Date` class with a method.

```
class Date
  def self.next_(weekday_string)
    // code here
  end
end
```

In my `application.rb` file I autoload everything in this `ext` folder

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib/ext"
```

But I keep getting the error `undefined method next_ for Date:Class`

Calling this method from within the console works fine

```
load 'lib/ext/date.rb'; Date.next_('wednesday')
=> Wed, 07 Oct 2015
```

And yes, the server has been restarted before trying to use this extended method.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better name for your method `def self.next(weekday)`?

Comment: It would be :) It used to be called `next_weekday` but I removed weekday. Not sure why I left the `_`

Comment: Did you restarted the Rails Server ?

Comment: Check the last line of the question @LukyBoy-KU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess, your understanding of Rails autoload mechanism is fuzzy.

`autoload_paths` is used when rails tries to resolve **undefined** constant. Say, you access a `User` for the first time. No such class is loaded, so rails will look in its autoload paths and try find `User` there.

Your case is different. `Date` is certain to be present (as it is a system class). And thus rails will have no reason to access files in autoload paths.

#### Solution:

load the files explicitly. For example, in an initializer

```
# 00_monkey_patching.rb
Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/monkey_patching/*.rb"].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

Comment: So I need to specifically load this class in?

Comment: Yes, you need to explicitly load it. Perhaps, in an initializer.

Comment: @CarlMarkham, also, [check out this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5654580/2235594) to extend core classes. I find the solution more elegant than using `monkey_patching` as a folder name.

Comment: @TheCha͢mp: using monkey_patching describes the purpose very well. That's what you do, patch stuff. If you need to patch, say, Mongoid driver, then `core_ext` would be a misleading name (because mongoid is not "core"). Also, the only different thing here is the folder name. So it's at the same level of elegance. :)

Comment: @TheCha͢mp: RE "genius" solution: it requires 3 lines less code, that's all. But drawbacks may be significant. Now your patches are scattered through the initializers folder. What if some of your other non-patching initializers rely on some patch, but that patch is not yet loaded at this point, due to lexicographical sorting?

Comment: Ye you got your points... :) Anyway, it was helpful since I learnt something new from you.

Comment: I agree an initializer is probably the most appropriate place for something like this.