# How do I prevent strip from dying when it encounters a non-UTF-8 character without manipulating my string before applying strip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, strip

I'm using Ruby 2.4 with Rails 5.  I have the following String

```
2.4.0 :005 > tr = doc.search("//td").first.text
 => "\r\n  \xA0PLACE \r\n  "
```

the String is UTF-8 encoded, although this is just an example.  I'm not guaranteed that all data will have UTF-8 encoding.

```
2.4.0 :007 > tr = doc.search("//td").first.text.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

but when I apply the "strip" method to it, the call dies

```
2.4.0 :006 > tr = doc.search("//td").first.text.strip
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

This is just an example, but how can I override the strip method so it doesn't die when it encounters a character it doesn't like?  I don't want to change the string in question.  I'm happy to write my own "strip" method, but I want to be able to keep the above exactly as I have it and just not have the error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea would be to make sure your data has correct encoding.

## Alternative

You could use :

```
"\r\n  \xA0PLACE \r\n  ".force_encoding('binary').strip
```

It returns :

```
"\xA0PLACE"
```

## Handle with care!!!!

If you feel adventurous, you could just override `String#strip` :

```
### Proof of concept
### HANDLE WITH CARE!!!
class String
  alias_method :original_strip, :strip
  def strip
    self.force_encoding('binary').original_strip
  end
end

p "\r\n  \xA0PLACE \r\n  ".strip
#=> "\xA0PLACE"
```

A [refinement](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) might limit the damage.

For a Rails project, you'd just need to put this code in an [initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654574/6419007).

Comment: Thanks but how do I override the strip function so that this is automatically included?  Although this works for my specific example, it would mean I would have to go through my entire application and replace "strip" with "force_encoding('binary').strip," which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You don't want to touch the strip method. It is used everywhere in many gems.

Comment: I do.  If other stuff breaks, that is my own damn fault, but when I said "how can I override the strip method" in my question, I genuinely mean it, crazy as it may seem.

Comment: Ahah! :D Roger that.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your updated answer.  THis is awesome!  Jus tone question -- where do I place the "class String" file?  Would I put that in my Rails installation or is there a project-specific place I can stick the file (please say a project-specific place)?

Comment: In Ruby, every class can be re-opened at any time. So you really can put this code wherever you want, as long as it is executed before you try to use this modified method. See update