# Extend Hash Class in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have a rails application where I need to extend the `Hash` module to add a method -

```
class Hash
  def delete_blank
    delete_if{|k, v| v.nil? or (v.instance_of?(Hash) and v.delete_blank.empty?)}
  end
end
```

I have created a filed named, hash_extensions.rb and placed this in my lib folder and of course configured autoloading paths with the following line in `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

When I call the delete blank method on a Hash however, I get the below error -

```
undefined method `delete_blank' for #<Hash:0x000000081ceed8>\nDid you mean?  delete_if
```

In addition to this, I have also tried placing `require "hash_extensions"` at the top of the file I am calling the delete_blank method from.

What am I doing wrong here or can I avoid extending Hash to have the same functionality?

Comment: Isn't the `self` causing the problems?

Comment: sorry I was just experimenting there, changed it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Ruby on Rails, to extend the String class, where should the code be put in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654517/in-ruby-on-rails-to-extend-the-string-class-where-should-the-code-be-put-in)

Comment: @MichaelVictor What is the Rails version that you are running?

Comment: Rails API 5.0.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could resolve this issue in a few different ways:

1. Assuming that `hash_extensions.rb` resides under `your_app/lib/extensions`. (It's a good idea to store all extensions  in a separate folder), require all extensions in `config/application.rb` as below:

   ```
   Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "extensions", "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }
   ```
2. Move `hash_extensions.rb` under `config/initializers` and it should be automoagically loaded.
3. Create a folder say `lib` or `extensions` under `your_app/app` and move `hash_extensions.rb` to it and Rails would take care of loading it.