# Rails make mb_chars default for upcase

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.2.9

I have a number of properties that store multibyte characters strings. I can use mb_chars to safely modify a string:

```
'a string'.mb_chars.upcase
```

but I want to avoid changing every occurrence of `.upcase` in my views to `.mb_chars.upcase`

Is it possible to configure Rails to use `mb_chars` by default, or is it safe to modify a String method like `upcase` to use mb_chars (if so, what is the best way of doing this)?

Comment: This can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654517/in-ruby-on-rails-to-extend-the-string-class-where-should-the-code-be-put-in