# Rails 6 with Zeitwerk: How to Extend Ruby Core Classes like Date, Time, String etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am upgrading a Rails 5.2.2 to Rails 6.0.0 that now has [Zeitwerk](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk).

Previously I had been extended core ruby classes like Date, Time, String, Float etc as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654517/in-ruby-on-rails-to-extend-the-string-class-where-should-the-code-be-put-in). Using an initializers file to load all files from the `lib/core_ext/*` folder. When starting a `rails server` it now errors an the last line of the stacktrace reads:

```
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:351:in `const_get': uninitialized constant CoreExt::Date (NameError)
```

Unfortunately, Zeitwerk is causing an error where `lib/core_ext/date.rb` etc is throwing an error that it has already been defined (when using `Rails.autoloaders.log!` in `application.rb`. `CoreExt::Date`

I have since moved the files directly to `initializers` (previously I just had the initializers directory with a file that loaded each file from the `'lib/core_ext/*` folder). This has fixed the issue for now but I'd like to keep `core_ext` folder and files where they were.

What have I missed here?

`lib/core_ext/date.rb`

```rb
class Date
  def to_sap
    strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
  end
end
```

I have tried wrapping explicitly in `CoreExt` but that did not help.

```
module CoreExt
  class Date
    def to_sap
      strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is saying on https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#file-structure

```
loader.push_dir(Rails.root.join("app/models"))
loader.push_dir(Rails.root.join("app/controllers"))
```

And by Zeitwerk author: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37835#issuecomment-560563560

> The lib folder does not belong to the autoload paths since Rails 3. @pixeltrix's is the recommended modern idiom if you want to autoload.
> Otherwise, lib belongs to $LOAD_PATH and you can require files in that directory.

We can call push_dir to load the lib subdirectories. My solution:

```rb
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb

Rails.autoloaders.main.push_dir(Rails.root.join('lib'))
```

or

```rb
# config/application.rb

  ...
  config.autoload_paths += [
    Rails.root.join('lib')
  ]
```

Then `CoreExt::Date` can be auto loaded.

Comment: Thank you. I have reviewed those comments you link and that answer looks like the way to do this (having a `lib/core_ext/date.rb` file for example) in Rails with Zeitwerk.

I have not tested this code in a new application yet but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work based on your sources. If others can confirm it would be great but for now I'll accept as the answer.

Comment: The comment above requested confirmation, so I thought I'd provide feedback. Installing Ruby extensions via the method described in this answer does not seem to work. There are no error messages, but the extensions don't get applied to the core Ruby classes. It seems like @dpaluy's answer (excluding extensions from Zeitwork and `require`-ing them explicitly may be the best way to apply such extensions.

Comment: It should work because zeitwerk enforces a convention. 
If you had to patch `CoreExt::Date`, down the track it is `push_dir('lib')` then create a date.rb following this lib/core_ext/date.rb
with `date.rb` includes the module
```ruby
module CoreExt
  class Date
  ...
  end
end

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dat Le Tien. Nevertheless It seems that with this solution i can only access my extended methods by explicitly specifying CoreExt::Array.

`Array.methods` doesn't show my methods but `CoreExt::Array.methods` do. I can't seem to find a solution where i can make them available without specifying the CoreExt module.

Comment: I am also stuck at the same problem.
Zeitwerk is not throwing any error but the methods added via class defined in our project are not getting included to original class. Please help if you have found some way

Answer (score 6):

I have the same structure by extending core functionality and adding files in `lib/extensions`

I solved this by adding

```
# config/application.rb
#
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(Rails.root.join('lib/extensions'))
end
```

And I keep initializing extensions as previously:

`Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'extensions', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }`

Comment: I doubt that this is the "correct" way to solve this issue, but the proposed solution worked. Thank you!

Comment: Adding a little more detail to this answer--the initialization line `Dir[Rails.root.join...` should go in a file in `config/initializers`. I used `config/initializers/01_includes.rb` to ensure it would be loaded first.

Comment: I've placed this line in the same initializer that loads the `lib/core_ext/*.rb` files. Additional info can be found here: https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#ignoring-parts-of-the-project Since we already load the `lib/core_ext/*.rb` files manually in an initializer there is no reason for Zeitwerk to autoload them (they are already loaded) or check them.