# How to properly monkey patch the Numeric class on RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how properly monkey patch a core DSL on RoR. I have the following monkey patch:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module CoreExtensions
  module Numeric
    def percent_of(number)
      to_f / number * 100.0
    end
  end
end
```

(I've followed this [article](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/)).

Now I would like to know where to put the following:

```
Numeric.include CoreExtensions::Numeric
```

I would like to have this `percent_of` method available for all my app. I've tried to place it in `config/application.rb`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.configure do
 # ...
end

Numeric.include CoreExtensions::Numeric
```

But it didn't work. When I try to serve the following error is raised:

```
uninitialized constant CoreExtensions (NameError)
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the path to the core extensions file?

Comment: You can place your monkeypatch in a file in the 'config/initalializers' directory. It will be required  during the initialization phase.

Comment: Since you are not using refinements, what would be wrong with just reopening and altering the class? Why would you ever need to declare a custom module and include it?

Comment: To expand on @AlekseiMatiushkin's suggestion, you can "reopen" the module in Ruby using the same syntax you would use to create a new module:

module Numeric;
  def percent_of(number);
    to_f / number * 100.0;
  end;
end

Comment: @KeithBennett `Numeric` is a class, not a module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Ruby on Rails, to extend the String class, where should the code be put in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654517/in-ruby-on-rails-to-extend-the-string-class-where-should-the-code-be-put-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) commented, you can use Rails [initializers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/configuring.html#using-initializers) folder for monkey patching the libraries.

I would suggest creating a new folder `core_extensions` within `config/initializers/` and group patches related to the same module/class in a separate file and place the `include` at the `last line`.

```
## File path: config/initializers/core_extensions/numeric.rb

# frozen_string_literal: true

module CoreExtensions
  module Numeric
    def percent_of(number)
      to_f / number * 100.0
    end
  end
end

Numeric.include CoreExtensions::Numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a file in `lib/extensions/` & called it `numeric_ext.rb` with this content:

```
class Numeric
  def percent_of(number)
   to_f / number * 100.0
  end
end
```

After that I included this snippet in my `application.rb`

```
config.to_prepare do
  load 'extensions/numeric_ext.rb'
end
```

I tested this & It's working properly.