# Create or rename method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to add method, or rename method name?

I have code like this:

```
"X Y".split().first => X
"X Y".split().last => Y
```

In a string, there is always only one space.

I'd like to change this to:

```
"X Y".a  => X
"X Y".b  => Y
```

How to achieve this goal?
Ryby 2.7, Rails 6

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do this in the first place since you can get character at any place in a string with:

```
"abc".chr == "a"
"abc"[0] == "a"
"abc"[-1] == "c"
```

If you really want to add methods to a string create a module:

```
module MyStringExtensions
  def a
    chr
  end

  def b
    self[-1]
  end
end
```

You can then extend string instances with the module to augment them:

```
"abc".extend(MyStringExtensions).a # "a"
```

You can also monkeypatch the String class if you really want to:

```
String.include(StringExtensions)
```

Using a module is generally better then reopening someone elses class as it gives a better stack trace for debugging.

Comment: You can also say `s = 'abc'; def s.a; split.first; end` to add a singleton method and then `s.a` does The Right Thing while leaving other strings alone. Curious as to what the real goal is though.

Answer (score 0):

You could create extensions methods for `String` class like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654517/in-ruby-on-rails-to-extend-the-string-class-where-should-the-code-be-put-in).

```
class String
  def a
    self.split().first
  end

  ...
end
```